# camel with twitter simple example

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am novice in apache-camel and I started with simple apache camel-twitter example using spring. I am using 2.20 version for camel and 2.19 version for camel-twitter. Below is my router code,

```
public class TwitterRouter extends RouteBuilder {

 public void configure() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Test");
     String twitter = "twitter://streaming/filter?type=event&keywords="+ URLEncoder.encode("london", "utf8")+"&consumerKey=key&consumerSecret=secretkey&accessToken=accesstoken&accessTokenSecret=accesstokensecret";

     from(twitter).process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                 Status status = exchange.getIn().getBody(Status.class);
                 ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
                 User user = status.getUser();
                 String name = user.getName();
                 System.out.println("name "+name);
                 template.sendBody("twitter","name "+name);
                 String screenName = user.getScreenName();
                 String text = status.getText();
           }
    });

     System.out.println("Test1");
}
```

And my spring context file as below,

```
<bean id="routeBuilder" class="com.xyz.route.TwitterRouter" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder" />

</camelContext>
```

So below are my queries,

1. After running program only Test and Test1 messages are printed on console. But whatever inside process method is not printed on console. I tried with producttemplate also but its not printing. So can anybody please help.
2. Also I tried to search for simpe camel-twitter example but not found. Does anybody have such example.

Comment: There are twitter examples with Apache Camel: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Comment: Also you should not mix Camel versions, use same Camel version for all your Camel JARs you have on the classpath, eg use either 2.19 or 2.20 version, do NOT mix them.

Comment: Hi Claus, Thanks I got my camel twitter example working. But one more question, has camel got connector with tika or any example of camel-tika would help me.